# Quick question on If statements with multiple conditions

Tags: java, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [&& (AND) and || (OR) in Java IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-java-if-statements)

This is a question I should have probably known the answer to years ago but if I am writing an if statement in Java that has something like if(x != null && y == null && x.equals(z)) is this safe?  I assume that the if statement conditions are interpreted from left to right so checking if x != null to begin with will assure no null pointer exception is thrown (at least by x) on the x.equals(z) part of the condition.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Such things are best checked by [consulting the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23). It is very strict, precise and is available for free, not like C++.

Comment: @Sergey: But it's a lot easier to ask on stackoverflow.com and get 4 answers in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It's called short-circuited logic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

like @mellamokb said it's short circuit.

I only add that if you have comparasion like that:

```
if (str != null && str.equals("FINAL STRING") {...}
```

better use:

```
if ("FINAL STRING".equals(str)) {...}
```

first way is very often choosen but conditions should be as simple as possible:)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You're just fine doing that.

The long answer: You're just fine doing that, because Java uses something called short circuit boolean evaluation.  Read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple: Yes, that is correct. :)