# servlet request.getParameterValues(fieldName) returns null and throw exception

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

i want to get parameters values and sometimes i do not send them and it return me `null` 
and its ok . but when i preform check on the return string array the servlet throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

and i just what to do nothing when its null. ( continue the flow )

```
String[] values = null; 
if(request.getParameterValues(fieldName).length>0)
{
    values = request.getParameterValues(fieldName);

    if(null!=values || values.length>0) // HERE IT throws NullPointerException 
    {
        Collections.addAll(strlist, values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
if(null!=values && values.length>0)
```

because, if your values is `null`(evaluating to `false`), the `OR` condition in your statement, executes the other part of the `OR`, which throws the `NPE`.

If you give an `&&` there, it'll [SHORT-CIRCUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the statement evaluation when it encounters a `false` at `null!=values`.

Comment: why , i what to check or this or that condition

Comment: @user63898 If you check using OR, then although `values` is null, you'll still do `values.length` which will throw NPE. If you have `&&`, if `values` is null, the second part won't be checked since `false && no_matter_what` is always false.

Comment: You can't do that. If you do it, then you're bound to get that exception! If values is `null`, `null.length` is bound to give you `NPE`.

Answer (score 1):

It's the AND && operator that should be used to test if both conditions are met, which is what you need in you instance.

```
if (null != values && values.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

in **and** unlike **or** if `values` is null it wont go for next check.

```
if(null!=values && values.length>0) // change to and 
 {
         Collections.addAll(strlist, values);
 }
```

also refer [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` follow short-circuit evaluation.

That is these operators wont execute right side expressions if not needed.

for `&&` operator if `false` at LHS, then it wont execute next expressions
for `||` operator if `true` at LHS, then it wont execute next expressions

so for your condition check it needs `&&` operation for avoiding `NullPointerException`

```
if(null!=values && values.length>0)
```