# Why does the "or" go before the "and"?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
int it=9, at=9;

if(it>4 || ++at>10 && it>0)  
{
    System.out.print("stuff");    
}

System.out.print(at);
```

prints out stuff9 and I want to know why as I thought `++at>10 && it>0` would be evaluated first and thus make at = 10.

Comment: Aside from the variable names, this is a good question. I don't see why it's downvoted.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - "go before" is not exactly sound terminology for what the OP is asking.  And this is all covered in any half decent Java textbook or tutorial.

Comment: @StephenC A lot of questions can be answered in a book or tutorial. He was using the knowledge that and precedes or, but didn't realize that short-circuiting resulted in unexpected output. That's a fair inquiry I think, regardless of whether or not short-circuiting is in a book. One might still think what he thought with that knowledge too.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - Now >>you<< are using bad terminology. AND does not "precede" or.  AND has a *higher precedence* than OR.  But anyway, I'm simply explaining why some people would think this is a bad question.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the correction, although I don't understand why "precede" is incorrect. Still, it's not a good reason to downvote, but I realize you're just pointing it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Operator precedence only controls argument grouping; it has no effect on execution order. In almost all cases, the rules of Java say that statements are executed from left to right. The precedence of `||` and `&&` causes the `if` control expression to be evaluated as

```
it>4 || (++at>10 && it>0)
```

but the higher precedence of `&&` does not mean that the `&&` gets evaluated first. Instead,

```
it>4
```

is evaluated, and since it's true, the short-circuit behavior of `||` means the right-hand side isn't evaluated at all.

Answer (score 9):

Your compound expression is equivalent to

```
if(it>4 || (++at>10 && it>0))
```

due to Java operator precedence rules. The operands of `||` are evaluated left to right, so `it>4` is evaluated first, which is `true`, so the rest of it (the entire `&&` subexpression) doesn't need to be evaluated at all (and so `at` does not change).

Answer (score 0):

I feel I should add how to actually get your expected output.

Brief explanation: the `||` operator [short-circuits](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Weekly/W02/SCBooleans.html) the entire expression, thus the right side not even being evaluated.

But, to *not* short-circuit and get your expected output, instead of the `||` operator, just use `|`, like so:

```
int a = 9, b = 9;

if(a>4 | ++b>10 && a>0)  
{
    System.out.print("stuff");    
}
System.out.print(b);
```

The output to that is `stuff10`

This way, regardless of one side being true or not, they're both still evaluated.

The same thing goes for `&&` and `&`