# && and || conditions in single IF Condition in PHP

Tags: php, oop, conditional-statements

I want to check whether the length of $a is 0 or if the length is not 0 then check if it is a numeric value in single IF statement in PHP. I tried this but not working

```
$a = '23bc';
if((strlen($a)===0 || (strlen($a)>0 && ctype_digit($a))) )
{
    echo 'Good to Go';
}
else
{
    echo 'Bad to Go';
}
```

I do not want to apply nested conditions here. Is it possible to do it in single IF statement?

I found this question here but this does not answers what I am asking for [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Comment: So you want to check if $a is equal 0 OR $a is numeric?

Comment: No I want to check if $a has a length of 0 or if it is not 0 then check if it is numeric

Comment: Looks like it works to me: "bad to go" because it's length greater than 0 but not all numeric

Comment: *" I tried this but not working"* What exactly is not working? What did you get and what did you expect (and why)?

Comment: Yes then if the $a is null then it should show good to go

Comment: Are you aware of what ctype_digit checks? It will return false if you pass 0 as an integer. If you want integers to pass the test you have to use is_numeric, as ctype_digit will interpret any integers as ASCII codes.

Comment: You want a: `good to go` if $a is NULL? that works for me

Comment: @Rizier123 did you try the whole code I have provided there?

Comment: @oelrim is_numberic will also let 0.0 as numeric while I want to be number only

Comment: @oelrim after your comment I tried ctype_digit giving $a='0'; and it correctly checked it.

Comment: @NoOneSeesMe ctype_digit(0) returns false for me, whereas ctype_digit('0') returns true.

Comment: Just use filter_var, done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know what your script is trying to achieve beyond using a one-liner in an if conditional concerning an empty string or a numeric string.  With cytpe_digit() every character must evaluate as a number to qualify as a numeric string.  You get a false result with '23bc' because of the 'bc' portion.

One of the problematic aspects with the script is that one don't know which condition results in a true.  One or the other conditions could be true or they could both be false.
See demo: http://3v4l.org/8Pchk.

You could rewrite the code making use of a ternary expression to have a one liner which eliminates the if-else construct, as follows:

```
<?php
$a = '23bc';

if( strlen( $a ) != 0) {
    echo ctype_digit( $a )? "Good to Go\n"  :  "Bad to Go\n";
}
```

The following may be more in line with what you're asking.  Here's the ultimate one-liner:

```
<?php
echo ( !strlen($a) || ctype_digit($a) )? "Good to Go\n"  :  "Bad to Go\n";
```

Because of the strictness of the identity operator `===` if $a is null, then you you'll see "Bad to Go.  You may either test for equality `strlen($a) == 0` or you can be more succinct by using the `!` operator (boolean NOT). See demo: http://3v4l.org/7cfV0