# OR operator - which statement is more efficient?

Tags: java

When I use the OR operator, only one expression has to be true. Is the first if statement more efficient because java checks only the first expression? Or does java check both?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        boolean test = true;

        if (test || calculate()) {
            // do something
        }

        if (calculate() || test) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public static boolean calculate() {
        // processor-intensive algorithm
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (test || calculate())
```

would never call `calculate()` when `test` is true, since `||` operator is short circuited, so that statement is more efficient when `test` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it is . because `calculate()` is never called , as long as `test` is true and it is the contract of `||` statements.

From [§15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24),

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | , but
>   evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand
>   operand is false.

Answer (score 0):

There are two or operators:

```
if ( condition | condition2 ){
```

Here, it will test the second condition regardless of the outcome of the second condition.

```
if ( condition || condition2 ){
```

Here, the second condition will only be checked if the first condition returned false.

The same way of double operators is implemented for the 'and' operators & and &&