# If Else Statement in vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I wanted to have this condition like i have `b2.text, c3.text, d4.text, e5.text, f6.text, g7.text, h8.text, i9.text and j10.text`.

And if they are all equal to zero then statement else continue.

i tried

```
If (b2.Text = 0 & c3.Text = 0 & d4.Text = 0 & e5.Text = 0 & f6.Text = 0 & g7.Text = 0 & h8.Text = 0 & i9.Text = 0 & j10.Text = 0) Then
            a1.Text = 10000000

        Else


Msgbox.Show("Cannot sort")
End if
```

Unfortunately i remembered & function only accept two variable only :P

How can i do it?
Thank you

Comment: can you share what you tried? what you shared is not a coding actually?

Comment: you forgot round braces

Comment: And also double ampersand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Comment: Im using VB.NET and it didnt work

Comment: please share your full code what you tried. then only we can sorted out?

Comment: If (b2.Text = 0 & c3.Text = 0 & d4.Text = 0 & e5.Text = 0 & f6.Text = 0 & g7.Text = 0 & h8.Text = 0 & i9.Text = 0 & j10.Text = 0) Then
            a1.Text = 1000

        Else

MsgBox.Show("Cant sort")

End if

Comment: You should set [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it will point out some problems for you. Also, do you mean that the textboxes are empty do you mean that they contain the *string* "0"?

Comment: Try using `= "0"` instead of `= 0`. You can't use **&**: use **And**, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want & for VB, you want AndAlso.  And while it is probably a bit above your level, you might want to look into Linq.

```
If ({b2.Text, c3.Text, d4.Text, e5.Text, f6.Text, g7.Text, h8.Text, i9.Text, j10.Text}).All(Function(f) f = "0") Then
    a1.Text = 10000000
Else
   Msgbox.Show("Cannot sort")
End IF
```

As others have said, you should turn on Option Strict, so that your comparison to an int gets flagged.  I made the string "0" above, but you could easily modify it to use length if that is what you actually need.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: yes, I thought about that, but decided fewer changes were better, particularly since it's possible that some of the values might not come from controls -- hopefully he doesn't actually name controls a,b and c.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what language are you using but I'm pretty sure you can compare more than 2 values The solution may be like this.

```
if (b2.text == 0 && c3.text == 0 && d4.text == 0 && e5.text== 0 && f6.text == 0 && g7.text == 0 && h8.text == 0 && i9.text == 0 && j10.text == 0) {
    //  when conditions are true
}
else {
   // else code here
}
```

Comment: I am using VB.NET :) I forgot to add it sorry