# SOS for Java boolean statement

Tags: java

Why this boolean statement is true?

```
a= 10;
b = 0;
7 < a || a == b && b > 9 - a / b
```

Since anything divided by 0 is error

Comment: Because `7 < a` and then the `||` isn't evaluated because the first condition is true.

Comment: Hint: how do you expect that expression to be evaluated?

Comment: good question. according to [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) && has precedence over ||. So why would || short circuit before &&?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [&& (AND) and || (OR) in IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795808/and-and-or-in-if-statements)

Comment: @JohnMercier This is weird (your link), in java && and || have the same "precedence level", and are executed from left to right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the first operand of the OR (`||`) operator (a > 7) evaluates to `true`, it short circuits and nothing else is evaluated. Therefore the entire expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Beat me to the clock :(

Comment: IDK why you got immediately 6 upvotes for such very easy question! Oh I forgot, you may be a moderator :D

Comment: @Yahya Mostly because it is explain simply in one line too. Other answers are not that easy to read

Comment: this is not a reason @AxelH also the rest of the answers explain that in one line maybe better, maybe because he is the first one who answer?? no idea, `?` i'm like Yahya

Comment: @YCF_L to be fair, I didn't upvote any because I believe there is duplicate for that question ;)

Answer (score 1):

`7 < a` returns true. Since it's  a `||` after, the rest isn't executed.

This is because `true || false` is true, and `true || true` is true too, so evaluing the second member is but a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your OR-Operator `||` uses lazy evaluation or [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means, since the very first expression `7 < a`is true, it won't evaluate any other statements including the one with a division by zero, since java already found something true.

If you actually want to get an error, you can use this OR-Operator `|` which should enforce the evaluation of all statements. Most only use it as a bitwise-operator, but its also a non-short-circuit version of `||`. For a more in-depth look at `||` vs. `|`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference).

For example,

```
boolean c = (7 < a | a == b && b > 9 - a / b);
```

will cause an ArithmeticExcption, as expected.